# How to work with a vector array of struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

So I have this struct:

```
struct foo{
    DWORD fooB;
    char *fooA;
}
```

and I have a variable `DWORD bar;`, so how do I find if `bar` matches any `fooB` in my struct?

EDIT: my Code (currently)

```
#include <algorithm> // for.   std::find

using namesapce std;

struct foo{
    DWORD fooB;
    char *fooA;
    // .... Use this
}

vector <DWORD> foo;


if ( std::find(vector.begin(), 
    vector.end(), pIdToFind) != 
    vector.end() )
    // We found the item in the list, so let's just continue 
else
// We haven't found it,
```

Comment: What's a vector array? What's `DWORD`?

Comment: [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933943/how-to-use-lambda-for-stdfind-if?rq=1 specifically the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934022/487892

Comment: this might be the answer, but I don't understand how to use it, sorry I'm new to C++

Comment: @jordancedrick I recommend starting here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply provide a comparison operator for comparing `DWORD`s to `foo`s:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <windows.h>

struct foo {
    DWORD fooB;
    char *fooA;
};

bool operator==(DWORD lhs, foo const &rhs)
{
    return lhs == rhs.fooB;
}

int main()
{
    foo needle{ 42, nullptr };
    vector<DWORD> haystack;

    if (std::find(haystack.begin(), haystack.end(), needle) != haystack.end())
    {
        // We found the item in the list, so let's just continue 
    }
    else
    {
        // not found
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But what do you call the `bool operator==(DWORD lhs, foo const &rhs)` in C++? since it's not a function

Comment: comparison operator. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/96-overloading-the-comparison-operators/

Comment: thanks!  if you wouldn't mind one last question, how is it used in the code?   EDIT: I havn't saw the link sorry, thanks

Comment: It *is* used by `std::find()`. To use it yourself, well, with it defined you can compare `DWORD`s too `foo`s: eg. `if (42 == foo{ 42, nullptr }) // .,. `