# Using find_if with a vector of pointers: How to pass pointer by const reference to lambda?

Tags: c++11, lambda, std, pass-by-pointer, pass-by-const-reference

In the following code I try to compare a vector of pointers via find_if and determine which contains a member a == 5 (in this case both of course, but it shows my case). However it doesn't compile.

```
#include <algorithm>

class obj
{
    public:
    int a = 5;
    int b = 2;
};

int main()
{
    obj A;
    obj B;
    std::vector<obj*> v = { &A, &B };

    std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), [](const (obj*)& instance) { if((*instance)->a == 5) return true; });
}
```

From what I interpreted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42933943/how-to-use-lambda-for-stdfind-if), find_if provides the actual vector entry as parameter to the lambda function which is traditionally taken up via const ref. But how do I specify this for pointers, because I have pointers as vector entries?

(For the lengthy error message take this code to godbolt using gcc 11.1 but I guess it's down to me not knowing how to specify the lambda argument correctly)

Comment: *why* do you need a const reference to a pointer? Pointers are cheap to copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to have const reference to pointer, not reference to const pointer:

```
[](obj* const& instance) { if(instance->a == 5) return true; return false; }
```

or with type alias for obj pointer, it is much clearer:

```
using PtrObj = obj*;
std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), [](const PtrObj& instance) { if(instance->a == 5) return true; return false; });
```

Comment: Thank you. This is so confusing... if this was algebra and I substituted your PtrObj for obj* I would get exactly the same as I was thinking first (const obj*&), but it's still wrong. Confusing C++...